# Get argument from pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs

Consider having the results from the pipe:

```
find .
```

Now I would like to access in the second command behind the pipe what is actually piped (inputed) and then for example to print it twice.

```
find . | printf $arg$arg\n
#each filename would be printed twice per line
```

Please note that the question is not asking about printing whatever once gets from pipe twice, I know how to use bash *for* loop or write a script that could accomplish the mentioned. **How I can get $arg** to use it quickly in inline scripts?

$0 and $1 do not work as they do in scripting files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer:** You can print each file twice using sed:

```
find . | sed 's/.*/& &/'
```

Sed can edit lines as they are inputted. The above command says `s` (substitute) `.*` (the entire line) `& &` (with itself, twice).

**Longer answer:** When you pipe one program into another, you're connecting the first program's *standard output stream* to the second program's *standard input stream*. Anything the first program prints will be treated as input for the second program.

Unfortunately for your example, the input doesn't come in line-by-line chunks that map nicely to a hypothetical `$args` variable. It comes in a big monolithic stream. If you want to print each line of the stream twice, you can use sed (which is a Stream EDitor), but it's just doing line-by-line replacements.

Answer (score 10):

Ignoring the possibility that file names contain newlines, you can use `sed` as [pringley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2616609/pringley) suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17847214/15168), or you can create a `while` loop with the `read` command:

```
find . |
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line$line"
done
```

(The `-r` is for 'raw' input; it stops the shell expanding backslash escape sequences in the input, and is a standard POSIX feature of the `read` command in the shell.)

Since you mention `bash`, you can avoid problems with newlines in the file names by using the `find . -print0` option to terminate each name by a null byte (`'\0'` in C) instead of a newline, and then use:

```
find . -print0 |
while read -r -d '' line
do
    echo "X${line}${line}X"
done
```

The `-d ''` replaces the normal newline delimiter with the first character of the string argument, but the string is empty so the first character is the only character is a null byte.

There isn't an easy way (nor, as far as I know, a hard way) to use a `for` loop along the lines of:

```
for line in $(find .)
do
    echo "X${line}${line}X"
done
```

which works reliably for names with spaces, or newlines in them.

Often, you may want to use the `xargs` command.  This reads standard input and creates a command line using what's read from standard input as arguments to the command.

```
find . | xargs wc -l
```

Or, with newline and space safety (by default, `xargs` splits arguments at spaces, tabs and newlines):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

There are a lot of options you can apply to `xargs` — especially the GNU version.

However, you also have options to `find` that largely make `xargs` redundant:

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} +
```

which does basically the same job as the `find . -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l` command.  One difference is that if there are no files in the output from `find`, then using `-exec` won't execute `wc` at all, whereas by default, `xargs` will execute it once (with no file name argument; this is for POSIX compliance).  With GNU `xargs`, you can use `-r` or `--no-run-if-empty` to stop that happening.  Mac OS X `xargs` seems to do that anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
find . | xargs -I{} printf "%s%s\n" {} {}
```

Comment: Consider `find . | xargs -I{} printf "%s between %s\n" {}{}`, try it, what would it print?

Comment: If you don't leave a space between `{}` and `{}`, I'd expect it to print "./file./file between ". If there *is* a space, I'd expect "./file between ./file"

Comment: I see, that is correct, I did not know what the braces were there for.