# How to call whatis command with program name from random selection from /bin?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line-arguments

I am working on homework assignment. The last question the `ls /bin | shuf -n 1` works to get a random command. But getting the `whatis` command to read the output from that isn't working.

[image]

Comment: basically asking the what the command would be to print out "did you know that: *insert whatis command of [ Ls /bin |  shuf -n 1 ]*"

Comment: the one shown in the snip is what i have but its not working. the bold print is th question, everything else is my answer.

Comment: I believe you want to use `xargs`. Something like `ls -1 /bin/ | shuf -n 1 | xargs whatis`. Or maybe `whatis $(ls -1 /bin/ | shuf -n 1)`. Also see [Get argument from pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17847103/608639).

Answer (score 0):

## Use `echo -n` and subshell

```
echo -n "Did you know that " && whatis -s1,8 $(ls -1 /bin | shuf -n 1)
```

- OR the old way with backticks -

```
echo -n "Did you know that " && whatis -s1,8 `ls -1 /bin | shuf -n 1`
```

### Comments:

`ls -1` provides single line output

`whatis -s1,8` limits man pages to sections 1 and 8